# How to post status updates to Facebook fan page via API?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I have spent the last few days going through Facebook docs and dozens of blogs/websites and I still cant figure out how to post a status update (to a fan page that I manage) via the Facebook API (programatically)?

This is normally a couple lines of code (with every other API in the world). I am just dumbfounded at the complexity and obscurity with Facebook.

Any pointers?

I don't want to build a UI or deal with sessions or use their "SDK", etc etc...I just want to do a RESTful HTTP POST/s (via PHP CURL).

Thanks in advance.

(BTW, I created an app (so I have an AppID and an AppSecret))

Comment: Well, this apprantly gets me an access code:
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token";
$parameterData = "client_id=$clientId&client_secret=$clientSecret&type=client_cred&scope=publish_stream,manage_pages,offline_access";

Then I tried a few things (with the access code), but I get various errors:

$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fanpage/feed";
$parameterData = "access_token=$accessToken&message=$message&picture=$picture&link=$link&name=$name&description=$description";
error

$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me";
$parameterData = "access_token=".urlencode($accessToken);
error

Answer (score 4):

First step (which you have done) is to get the user access token with the publish_stream, manage_pages permissions. Call this USER_ACCESS_TOKEN.

Step 2, get the page access token and use that to publish to the page wall. Getting page access_token:

1. Call to URL /me/accounts with the USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
2. The result should include your fanpage and corresponding page token. Get that token, call this PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN
3. Then to post to the page wall, call /PAGE_ID/feed with your parameters and use the
   PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN

For more details, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/ (look for Page Access Tokens and feed sections)

Comment: So in step 2 (part 1), here's the error I get:  
Response: {"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."}}  
This was returned by invoking php CURL:  
$url = "graph.facebook.com/me/accounts";  
$parameterData = array();  
$parameterData['access_token'] = $userAccessToken;  
(extracted from previous graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token call

Comment: And here's the 1st call to get the userAccessToken:  $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token";  
  
  
$parameterData = array();  
$parameterData['client_id'] = "xxx";  
$parameterData['client_secret'] = "xxx";  
$parameterData['type'] = "client_cred";  
$parameterData['scope'] = "publish_stream,manage_pages";

Comment: Anyone have any clues? Whats wrong with the "access token"? The 'key' & 'secret' are tied to my personal facebook account/id (I created the app), so why can't I access my own "user"? Is it not possible to access/update the pages "I" manage programatically (via script)?

Comment: Your issue is with the userAccessToken. The method you were using was pre-OAuth2.0 which Facebook is currently using. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ for more details on how to get a user access_token.

Comment: How do images work? Do they get posted to /PAGE_ID/photos or feed?

Comment: For receive the page access token, you should be part of the "page roles" eg admin / mod / editor etc. If you dont have any role for the page, you don't have any permission to post like an admin (with your user access token, you can write also feed/post to the page, but its only visible on the page itself as "post to page" section).